# How can I not display page number = 1 in pdf ? (hmtl css)

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, dompdf

My code html like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Print PDF</title>

        <style type="text/css"> 
            .footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 50px;text-align: center; }
            .footer .pagenum:before { content: counter(page); }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is test</h1>

        <table class="tg">
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 1</th>
                <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 2</th>
                <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 3</th>
                <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 4</th>
                <th class="tg-3wr7">kolom 5</th>
            </tr>
            @php ($row = 22)
            @for($i=0;$i<$row;$i++)
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
                <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
                <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
                <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
                <td class="tg-rv4w">test 1</td>
            </tr>
            @endfor
        </table>

         <div class="footer">
            <span class="pagenum"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If $row = 22, it will display only 1 page like this :

[image]

If $row = 202, it will display 7 page like this ;

[image]

When there is more than 1 page, the first page does not display the page number.

But when there is only 1 page, first page displays page number

What I want is :

I want to disappear the page number when there is only 1 page

How can I do it?

Comment: Show us your code for exporting to the pdf

Answer (score 0):

> Update Regarding [changes](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases) with version of dompdf >= 0.7.0
>
> 1. Because the dompdf_config.inc.php file has been removed from this release (and is no longer referenced) all dompdf options should be set  at run time.
> 2. The FontMetrics class is now instantiated instead of static. To simplify migration of embedded scripts from earlier versions of dompdf
>      we provide access to the instantiated `FontMetrics` class via the
>      `$fontMetrics` variable. Please update your embedded scripts. For
>      example, `FontMetrics::get_font('helvetica')` would now be
>      `$fontMetrics->getFont('helvetica')`.
>
> ~ Thanks to [Dennis Ameling's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4337765/dennis-ameling)
>   [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983610/how-to-get-page-number-on-dompdf-pdf-when-using-view/#answer-38788676) for the updated information.

by looking over the `dompdf_config.inc.php` file. As it turns out, `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` is set to `false` thus causing the inline php script to be ignored. I simply edited `dompdf_config.custom.inc.php` to the following and all is fine and working with the later code in the  `view`.

In dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php

```
<?php
    define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP", true);
```

At Run Time

```
$dompdf->set_option("isPhpEnabled", true);
```

Then, in my html file

```
<body>
    <script type="text/php">
        if ( isset($pdf) ) {
            // OLD 
            // $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
            // $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(255,0,0));
            // v.0.7.0 and greater
            $x = 72;
            $y = 18;
            $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
            $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
            $size = 6;
            $color = array(255,0,0);
            $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
            $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
            $angle = 0.0;   //  default
            $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
        }
    </script>
    <div>
```

If you go this route, don't forget to restart Apache