# How to add content using @page blocks

Tags: css

I'm trying to add content to a printed webpage using an @page block. I've seen plenty of examples of this but it doesn't seem to work

Using the html below I expect to see the word "Hello" in the top left corner of the page when I do a Print Preview... can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css">
            @media print {
                @page {
                    size: 8.5in 11in;
                    margin: 0.5in;

                    @top-left {
                        content: "Hello";
                    }
                }
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Page content</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because _You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be ignored_. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: If that's true then why are there so many examples of people adding content within page blocks... [example1](https://www.servoyforge.net/boards/2/topics/215?r=216#message-216) [example2](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-css2-971104/page.html#h-12.3.5) [example3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8476948/669645)

Comment: example1 and 3 are over 3 years old, don't know what you meant with example 2. But it is a draft, so not (fully) supported.

Comment: Sorry... just fixed link for example 2

Comment: A comment for the down vote would be useful...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this functionality probably used to work... I'm not really sure on that though. There are enough examples around the internet to suggest that it has been in use.

The current specification does not allow for this sort of functionality so I guess that's that.

The current working draft does support content being added through the page block but it hasn't made it into the specification so is not currently supported by any browsers.